# "Выбросить как ненужный хлам"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как, сравнительный-оборот

*... а потом нас выбросят как ненужный хлам...*  Нужна ли здесь запятая перед "как"?
Заранее благодарна за ответы.

Answer (score 4):

Если "выбросить как ненужный хлам" - это устойчивое сочетание. то запятая не нужна.(блестит как зеркало. красный как рак). Если еще выражение "выбросить как хлам" можно посчитать устойчивым, то добавление слова "ненужный" (бывает нужный хлам? если нужный, то это не хлам) дает право запятую поставить.

Comment: Ну, почему бы не быть нужному хламу. Может, он дорог как память. Или дыру в окне закрывает.  

> — А плохая баба? — сказал декабрист. — Разве не нужна бывает и плохая баба?  
> — Конечно! Конечно, нужна, — отвечал я ему. — Хорошему человеку плохая баба иногда прямо необходима бывает.

Comment: В одном из значений слова "хлам" есть слова "нечто ненужное", поэтому словосочетание "нужный хлам" противоречит самому себе, а в "ненужный хлам" прилагательное избыточно.

Comment: Ну, зачем так строго! язык - вещь прихотливая... Это может быть авторским ходом, например, для создания парадокса.  

По-моему хлам - это что-то ветхое, старое, плохое. Но при отсутствии достатка и такому будешь рад!

Answer (score 1):

А почему, собственно, "выбросить как хлам" - устойчивое словосочетание?, или, тем более, "выбросить как ненужный хлам"? Кроме того, как мне кажется, ни первое ни второе сравнительным оборотом не являются, поэтому запятая не ставится. То, что нужно выбросить не сравнивается со старым хламом, а определяется как старый хлам.

"§ 150. Запятыми выделяются **сравнительные обороты**, начинающиеся союзами как, словно, точно, будто (как будто), что, как и, чем, нежели и т. п., например:

...Покойно, как лодка, скользит по каменной глади автомобиль (Федин
А вот в выражении "Пришлось выбросить его на свалку истории,как ненужный хлам".

Answer (score 1):

ПРАВИЛЬНО: нас выбросят, как ненужный хлам.

Это не сравнение, а отождествление, при этом рассматриваются два варианта: причинное значение и значение "в качестве". Здесь оборот с союзом КАК имеет причинное значение: так как посчитают ненужным хламом. Думаю, что выражение "выбрасывать в качестве хлама" смотрится хуже, это применять что-то можно "в качестве".

ПРИМЕРЫ

(1)  Обособленный вариант:"Но окружающие не постеснялись ― дневник и письма, хранившиеся у Орловой, были уничтожены ими, как ненужный хлам». "Почему же их отбрасывают теперь, как ненужный хлам, чем же им жить ― подачками"?

(2)В то же время встречаются варианты без обособления: "Ге попал в Петербург (1863) в самое неблагоприятное для искусства, нигилистическое время, когда во всем признавалась только утилитарность и когда бесцельное искусство отвергалось как ненужный хлам".